# R Why does nclass.FD return a different number of bins than the hist function?

Tags: r, histogram

Why does `nclass.FD` result in a different number of bins than the `hist`?

`nclass.FD` gives me 354 bins.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10^6)
nclass.FD(x)
```

`hist`on the other hand gives me 478 bins.

```
length(hist(x, breaks = "FD", plot = FALSE)$counts)
```

The manual says that `breaks = "FD"` means that `nclass.FD` is used for the histogram.

> Other names for which algorithms are supplied are "Scott" and "FD" / "Freedman-Diaconis" (with corresponding functions nclass.scott and class.FD).

So, why do I get a different number of bins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it you look at the text under `breaks` in `?hist` you see:

> In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to pretty values, the number is limited to 1e6 (with a warning if it was larger).

and `breaks="FD"` is one of the last three cases referred to.

If you just do :

```
y<-hist(x, breaks = "FD", plot = FALSE)
pretty(y$breaks)
```

The breaks you get are:

```
 -6 -4 -2  0  2  4  6
```

which is not what `hist` is using.

If you try various options with `pretty()` you find that you get 97 breaks with:

```
 pretty(y$breaks, n=136) 
 [1] -4.9 -4.8 -4.7 -4.6 -4.5 -4.4 -4.3 -4.2 -4.1 -4.0 -3.9 -3.8 -3.7 -3.6 -3.5 -3.4 -3.3 -3.2 -3.1
[20] -3.0 -2.9 -2.8 -2.7 -2.6 -2.5 -2.4 -2.3 -2.2 -2.1 -2.0 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5 -1.4 -1.3 -1.2
[39] -1.1 -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
[58]  0.8  0.9  1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6
[77]  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.0  3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4  4.5
[96]  4.6  4.7
```

If you use any number between 137 and 341 for `n` you get the following 193 breaks:

```
pretty(y$breaks, n=137)
  [1] -4.90 -4.85 -4.80 -4.75 -4.70 -4.65 -4.60 -4.55 -4.50 -4.45 -4.40 -4.35 -4.30 -4.25 -4.20 -4.15
 [17] -4.10 -4.05 -4.00 -3.95 -3.90 -3.85 -3.80 -3.75 -3.70 -3.65 -3.60 -3.55 -3.50 -3.45 -3.40 -3.35
 [33] -3.30 -3.25 -3.20 -3.15 -3.10 -3.05 -3.00 -2.95 -2.90 -2.85 -2.80 -2.75 -2.70 -2.65 -2.60 -2.55
 [49] -2.50 -2.45 -2.40 -2.35 -2.30 -2.25 -2.20 -2.15 -2.10 -2.05 -2.00 -1.95 -1.90 -1.85 -1.80 -1.75
 [65] -1.70 -1.65 -1.60 -1.55 -1.50 -1.45 -1.40 -1.35 -1.30 -1.25 -1.20 -1.15 -1.10 -1.05 -1.00 -0.95
 [81] -0.90 -0.85 -0.80 -0.75 -0.70 -0.65 -0.60 -0.55 -0.50 -0.45 -0.40 -0.35 -0.30 -0.25 -0.20 -0.15
 [97] -0.10 -0.05  0.00  0.05  0.10  0.15  0.20  0.25  0.30  0.35  0.40  0.45  0.50  0.55  0.60  0.65
[113]  0.70  0.75  0.80  0.85  0.90  0.95  1.00  1.05  1.10  1.15  1.20  1.25  1.30  1.35  1.40  1.45
[129]  1.50  1.55  1.60  1.65  1.70  1.75  1.80  1.85  1.90  1.95  2.00  2.05  2.10  2.15  2.20  2.25
[145]  2.30  2.35  2.40  2.45  2.50  2.55  2.60  2.65  2.70  2.75  2.80  2.85  2.90  2.95  3.00  3.05
[161]  3.10  3.15  3.20  3.25  3.30  3.35  3.40  3.45  3.50  3.55  3.60  3.65  3.70  3.75  3.80  3.85
[177]  3.90  3.95  4.00  4.05  4.10  4.15  4.20  4.25  4.30  4.35  4.40  4.45  4.50  4.55  4.60  4.65
[193]  4.70
```

and at 342 you get the 479 breaks (=478 bins) that `hist` is using;

```
pretty(y$breaks, n=342)
  [1] -4.90 -4.88 -4.86 -4.84 -4.82 -4.80 -4.78 -4.76 -4.74 -4.72 -4.70 -4.68 -4.66 -4.64 -4.62 -4.60
 [17] -4.58 -4.56 -4.54 -4.52 -4.50 -4.48 -4.46 -4.44 -4.42 -4.40 -4.38 -4.36 -4.34 -4.32 -4.30 -4.28
 [33] -4.26 -4.24 -4.22 -4.20 -4.18 -4.16 -4.14 -4.12 -4.10 -4.08 -4.06 -4.04 -4.02 -4.00 -3.98 -3.96
 [49] -3.94 -3.92 -3.90 -3.88 -3.86 -3.84 -3.82 -3.80 -3.78 -3.76 -3.74 -3.72 -3.70 -3.68 -3.66 -3.64
 [65] -3.62 -3.60 -3.58 -3.56 -3.54 -3.52 -3.50 -3.48 -3.46 -3.44 -3.42 -3.40 -3.38 -3.36 -3.34 -3.32
 [81] -3.30 -3.28 -3.26 -3.24 -3.22 -3.20 -3.18 -3.16 -3.14 -3.12 -3.10 -3.08 -3.06 -3.04 -3.02 -3.00
 [97] -2.98 -2.96 -2.94 -2.92 -2.90 -2.88 -2.86 -2.84 -2.82 -2.80 -2.78 -2.76 -2.74 -2.72 -2.70 -2.68
[113] -2.66 -2.64 -2.62 -2.60 -2.58 -2.56 -2.54 -2.52 -2.50 -2.48 -2.46 -2.44 -2.42 -2.40 -2.38 -2.36
[129] -2.34 -2.32 -2.30 -2.28 -2.26 -2.24 -2.22 -2.20 -2.18 -2.16 -2.14 -2.12 -2.10 -2.08 -2.06 -2.04
[145] -2.02 -2.00 -1.98 -1.96 -1.94 -1.92 -1.90 -1.88 -1.86 -1.84 -1.82 -1.80 -1.78 -1.76 -1.74 -1.72
[161] -1.70 -1.68 -1.66 -1.64 -1.62 -1.60 -1.58 -1.56 -1.54 -1.52 -1.50 -1.48 -1.46 -1.44 -1.42 -1.40
[177] -1.38 -1.36 -1.34 -1.32 -1.30 -1.28 -1.26 -1.24 -1.22 -1.20 -1.18 -1.16 -1.14 -1.12 -1.10 -1.08
[193] -1.06 -1.04 -1.02 -1.00 -0.98 -0.96 -0.94 -0.92 -0.90 -0.88 -0.86 -0.84 -0.82 -0.80 -0.78 -0.76
[209] -0.74 -0.72 -0.70 -0.68 -0.66 -0.64 -0.62 -0.60 -0.58 -0.56 -0.54 -0.52 -0.50 -0.48 -0.46 -0.44
[225] -0.42 -0.40 -0.38 -0.36 -0.34 -0.32 -0.30 -0.28 -0.26 -0.24 -0.22 -0.20 -0.18 -0.16 -0.14 -0.12
[241] -0.10 -0.08 -0.06 -0.04 -0.02  0.00  0.02  0.04  0.06  0.08  0.10  0.12  0.14  0.16  0.18  0.20
[257]  0.22  0.24  0.26  0.28  0.30  0.32  0.34  0.36  0.38  0.40  0.42  0.44  0.46  0.48  0.50  0.52
[273]  0.54  0.56  0.58  0.60  0.62  0.64  0.66  0.68  0.70  0.72  0.74  0.76  0.78  0.80  0.82  0.84
[289]  0.86  0.88  0.90  0.92  0.94  0.96  0.98  1.00  1.02  1.04  1.06  1.08  1.10  1.12  1.14  1.16
[305]  1.18  1.20  1.22  1.24  1.26  1.28  1.30  1.32  1.34  1.36  1.38  1.40  1.42  1.44  1.46  1.48
[321]  1.50  1.52  1.54  1.56  1.58  1.60  1.62  1.64  1.66  1.68  1.70  1.72  1.74  1.76  1.78  1.80
[337]  1.82  1.84  1.86  1.88  1.90  1.92  1.94  1.96  1.98  2.00  2.02  2.04  2.06  2.08  2.10  2.12
[353]  2.14  2.16  2.18  2.20  2.22  2.24  2.26  2.28  2.30  2.32  2.34  2.36  2.38  2.40  2.42  2.44
[369]  2.46  2.48  2.50  2.52  2.54  2.56  2.58  2.60  2.62  2.64  2.66  2.68  2.70  2.72  2.74  2.76
[385]  2.78  2.80  2.82  2.84  2.86  2.88  2.90  2.92  2.94  2.96  2.98  3.00  3.02  3.04  3.06  3.08
[401]  3.10  3.12  3.14  3.16  3.18  3.20  3.22  3.24  3.26  3.28  3.30  3.32  3.34  3.36  3.38  3.40
[417]  3.42  3.44  3.46  3.48  3.50  3.52  3.54  3.56  3.58  3.60  3.62  3.64  3.66  3.68  3.70  3.72
[433]  3.74  3.76  3.78  3.80  3.82  3.84  3.86  3.88  3.90  3.92  3.94  3.96  3.98  4.00  4.02  4.04
[449]  4.06  4.08  4.10  4.12  4.14  4.16  4.18  4.20  4.22  4.24  4.26  4.28  4.30  4.32  4.34  4.36
[465]  4.38  4.40  4.42  4.44  4.46  4.48  4.50  4.52  4.54  4.56  4.58  4.60  4.62  4.64  4.66
```

Where now each break 0.02 greater than the next. It looks like the `hist` command is feeding in the bins from the `nclass.FD` formula, but then pretty increases the number to make nice even rounded breakpoints, and it somehow chooses to use the breaks that are 0.02 apart. Why it chooses that in particular I don't know.

**EDIT:**
Just noticed that if you do `pretty(x, n=354)`, you get the same 479 breaks that `hist` gives you.  `x` ranges from -4.882127 to 4.650944, so if you want to use the `FD` breaks, but make them nice and even, then you end up with the 479 bins from`hist`.